# Generar CSV con multiples registros con un solo Formulario

Tags: php, formularios, csv

como estan? Les cuento que soy nuevo en la Programacion...Necesito crear un csv con n filas o registros usando un mismo Formulario...al momento cuento con el siguiente codigo el cual me genera dicho csv pero solo con 1 registro al usar el boton submit. necesitaria agregar mas registros antes de generar dicho archivo csv.

```
    if(isset($_POST['generaCSV'])){

//collect form data
$inpNombre = $_POST['inpNombre'];
$inpDeployState = $_POST['inpDeployState'];
$inpIncidentState = $_POST['inpIncidentState'];
$inpRespTecnico = $_POST['inpRespTecnico'];
$inpRespServicio = $_POST['inpRespServicio'];
$inpSistOp = $_POST['inpSistOp'];
$inpClteProy = $_POST['inpClteProy'];
$inpIp = $_POST['inpIp'];
$inpPropFunc = $_POST['inpPropFunc'];
$inpObserv = $_POST['inpObserv'];


//Chequea el cambo Nombre
if($inpNombre ==''){
    $error[] = 'Se requiere ingresar el Nombre corto de la VM (Sin Dominio)';
}

//if no errors carry on
if(!isset($error)){

    # Titulos de columnas CSV
    $Content = "Name;\"Deployment State\";\"Incident State\";\"Responsable_Tecnico\";\"Responsable_del_Servicio\";\"Sistema_Operativo\";\"Cliente_o_Proyecto\";\"IP\";\"Proposito/Funcion\";\"Observaciones\"\n";

    //establecer los datos del CSV
    $Content .= "$inpNombre;\"$inpDeployState\";\"$inpIncidentState\";\"$inpRespTecnico\";\"$inpRespServicio\";\"$inpSistOp\";\"$inpClteProy\";\"$inpIp\";\"$inpPropFunc\";\"$inpObserv\"";



    # establecer el nombre del archivo y crear el archivo CSV
    $FileName = "formdata-".date("d-m-y-h:i:s").".csv";
    header('Content-Type: application/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $FileName . '"');
```

Comment: te sugiero leer este tutorial..

Comment: https://www.webslesson.info/2017/09/how-to-store-form-data-in-csv-file-using-php.html

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta...estoy verificando lo indicado y te contare..muchas gracias.